How to Execute a Javascript Callback based on a Variable or Parameter
I have an array that is passed to React from a Laravel back end, representing columns in a database. I iterate over this array to construct headings for a table.
For each column, I want to run a callback function to mutate or transform the corresponding data (of each row) for each column.
For example, a Boolean would be transformed, so "Yes", or "No" for 1 or 0 (a TinyInt). Here is what I have so far.
const callbacks = {
    name: function(name) {
        console.log(name);
    },
    completed: function(name) {
        console.log(name);
    },
    created_at: function(name) {
        console.log(name);
    },
    updated_at: function(name) {
        console.log(name);
    },
};

The React component that builds each row of the table is below.
Edit
Added supporting React components.
export default function Row({ can, buttons, row }) {
    
    

    return (
        <>
            {
                Object.keys(row).map((k, i) => {
                    if(k !== "id") { 
                        return ( <td key={ i } className="whitespace-nowrap p-4">{ row[k] }</td> )
                    }
                })
            }
            { buttons(can, row.id) }
        </>
    );
}

The following components below are related to the  component, but not the question and solution sought.
import Columns from "./Columns";
import Rows from "./Rows";

export default function DataTable(props) {
    
    return (
        <> 
            { props?.control }
            { props?.pagination }
                
            <div className="flex flex-col">
                <div className="overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                    <div className="inline-block min-w-full py-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        <div className="overflow-hidden">
                            <table className="min-w-full text-left text-md text-gray-700">
                                
                                <Columns columns={ props?.columns } />
                                <Rows 
                                    can={ props.can }
                                    buttons={ props.buttons }
                                    rows={ props?.rows?.data } 
                                />
                                
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            { props?.pagination }
        </>
    );
}

import Row from "./Row";

export default function Rows({ can, buttons, rows }) {

    return (
        <>
            {
                rows?.length > 0 && (
                    <tbody>
                    {
                        rows?.map(row => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={ row.id }>
                                    <Row 
                                        can={ can }
                                        buttons={ buttons }
                                        row={ row } 
                                    />
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    </tbody>
                ) 
            }
        </>
    );
}

import Button from "../../../../Common/DataTable/Button";
import routeService from "../../../../Utilities/routeService";

export default function ButtonGroup(can, id) { 

    return (
        <>
            <td className="whitespace-nowrap p-4">
                    
                { can.show && <Button clickHandler={ (e) => routeService.info(route("clients.show", { client: id })) }>Info</Button> }
                { can.edit && <Button clickHandler={ (e) => routeService.edit(route("clients.edit", { client: id })) }>Edit</Button> }
                { can.delete && <Button clickHandler={ (e) => routeService.destroy(route("clients.destroy", { client: id })) } danger={ true }>Delete</Button> }

            </td>
        </>
    );
}

export default function Button({ clickHandler, danger, children }) {

    return (
        <button 
            onClick={ () => clickHandler() }
            className={
                danger ? (
                    "inline-flex items-center mx-2 px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-red-500 active:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                ) : (
                    "inline-flex items-center mx-2 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 focus:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                )
            }>
            { children }
        </button>
    );
} 

Where the { row[k] } is outputted, is where I need to transform the data, based on the available callback functions and the column name, found in the variable k.
Can anyone help me figure this out? There's likely an easy way to do this dynamically but I don't know enough Javascript to figure it out.
I tried using an array to "map" the column names to the callback function, but I couldn't get that to work.
I also may need to associate a column name to a different callback function, such as a callback function named active for numerous column names, ie completed, banned, has_uploaded, etc - anything that could also be Boolean.

You could replace { row(k) } with { callbacks[k](row[k]) }

How is <Row> called? It's not clear what data you are passing as props, please [edit] your question to give an example. Also why are all of your callbacks just logging the value and not doing any of the mutation/transformation that you are speaking of? They probably should return something.

Dynamic Callback Execution: You determine whether a callback for the column name k exists inside the map function. If so, you use the row data row[k] to call that method. Otherwise, you just give back the initial value.
General Boolean Handling: By modifying your callbacks object as necessary, you can utilize the same callback for the active status as well as additional Boolean attributes like completed, banned, and has_uploaded.
Returning Transformed Value: Every transformed value is presented in the table cell after being saved in transformedValue.
